# Incomplete output after concatenation

Tags: java, concatenation

I am new to java and I am trying to concatenate two strings, say,

```
String string1 = "Paris"
String string2 = "is a great place to visit"
```

I tried using `concat` , `+` and also `StringBuilder`, but every time I'm getting same output i.e. `"Paris is"`.

Please help me out.

Comment: Post your code !!

Comment: Sounds like it may well be a problem with how you're checking it. Maybe there's a U+0000 character after `is` and whatever you're using for output is truncating there? Without more information, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: `concat()` method returns a new `String` object.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
public class Concat
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  String string1 = "Paris";
  String string2 = " is a great place to visit.";
  System.out.println(string1.concat(string2));
  }
}
```